# String operation

Tags: ruby, string

What's simplest way to turn the string "YingYang" into "Ying/Yang"?

Comment: "YingYang".replace("Ying/Yang") :-)

Comment: If you are asking the 'simplest', this is it. But dont know whether its useful or not

keruilin, can you elaborate what you really want to do here ...

cheers
sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to insert a slash everywhere where a lower case letter is followed by a capital letter:

```
"YingYang".gsub(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '\1/\2')
```

Comment: I prefer to use named character classes, since they will work with *all* upper/lower characters while explicitly listing them like you do will only work for, well, the ones between *a* and *z* : `"YingYang".gsub(/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/, '\1/\2')`. Plus, it's more intention-revealing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: At least on 1.8.7 (with $KCODE set to "u") `"ÖÄÜ" =~ /[:upper:]/` returns nil, so I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, but it *does* work on Oniguruma, i.e. Ruby 1.9 and also 1.8 with the Oniguruma extension. It also works on JRuby both on 1.9 and 1.8, because it uses JOni (line-by-line Java transliteration of Oniguruma) even in 1.8 mode. And it doesn't hurt on MRI 1.8. Plus, it makes the intent clearer (IMO).

Comment: An alternative, look-behind: `s.gsub(/(?<=[[:lower:]])[[:upper:]]/, '/\&')`